# WooCommerce Variable Products - Can't choose products with '0' as an attribute - Error 'please choose all product options'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I've been developing an e-commerce store for a client using WooCommerce and I've come across a very strange issue. All of my products are variable products and I have set them up like this:
Variation 1 - Weight (0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0...5.0 in Kgs)
Variation 2 - Units  (0,1,2,3,4,5...10)
Variation 3 - Cut Type (Ground, Slices, Whole etc)
I set the variations in such a way that a customer has to choose either Variation 1 or Variation 2 (weight or in units) and Variation 3. If they choose to purchase a product by Weight (Weight is great than '0') the only choice in 'Units' is 0 and vice versa. This worked for me for a day or two and stopped working, I keep getting an error 'please select product options'..
I then changed the '0' value to 'Zero' and the combination works, has anyone come across this problem before? 
I tried to switch to the default theme of WP and shut off all plugins except WooCommerce but nothing works.
Any ideas?

Link to a product page - http://www.best-foods-for-fat-burning.com/wordpress/?product=%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%90%D7%93%D7%95

Thanks,
Ofer

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. I've tested it on several different installation. Using the latest versions of Woocommerce 2.0.20 and WordPress 3.8.1. The best thing to do is add additional info like 0-Kgs to your attribute slug and that solves the problem until woothemes fixes this bug.